# Extract the hash from Torrent File in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, bittorrent

I was hoping to extract the hash identifier for a torrent file.

Particularly, I'm looking for the same hash that shows up in Transmission/uTorrent upon opening up a torrent info dialogue (It looks like this: 7b435a6f051dec092a6ee440d793bfed6696cfa1)

I *think* that it's the SHA1 hash from the info dictionary on the torrent file. If I were to parse over the binary file data from one byte to another byte, then perform a SHA1 hash encryption I could get it.

Does anyone have a better understanding or have some code that could do this?

Answer (score 4):

Using the [bencode](https://github.com/dasch/ruby-bencode) gem:

```
require 'bencode'
require 'digest/sha1'

meta = BEncode.load_file(file) # File or file path
info_hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(meta["info"].bencode)
```

Comment: your answer work very well, however can you update you'r answer with 2 things: 1. point on some documentation where it state that this hash is a SHA1 hash of whole info part of torrent file. 2 - why you take SHA1 from bencoded info, not from bdecoded?

Comment: @SET there isn't any, it appears to be a popularly-adopted convention not part of the actual bit torrent specification. That's why you don't read the info hash from the torrent itself. The info hash is quite simply the SHA1 hash of the "info" section of the torrent (as-is; un-bdecoded). The "info" section encapsulates everything that would uniquely identify a torrent ( [docs](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure) ). More info: http://ktorrent.org/wiki/index.php/Info_hash

Answer (score 1):

You could try [RubyTorrent](https://github.com/dydx/RubyTorrent), there is an example of how to dump meta data from a .torrent file here: https://github.com/dydx/RubyTorrent/blob/master/dump-metainfo.rb

There is also a [bencode](https://github.com/dasch/ruby-bencode) gem that can be used to parse .torrent files.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [firecracker](https://github.com/oleander/firecracker-rb) gem

```
require "firecracker"
require "bencode_ext"
require 'open-uri'

torrent = open(link).read

# Get the info_hash from torrent file
info_hash = Firecracker.hash(torrent.bdecode)
puts "Info Hash = " + info_hash
```